# No notification upon post deletion by moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, notifications

[My answer (2k+ only)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116888/56090) to a code golf was rightfully deleted by a moderator because it turned out to be wrong and unfixable.

This morning, I planned to delete it myself, but all direct links to my answer or its question from my profile/notification list were removed too. I had to search the question from what I recalled of it to find it and read the last comments.

Why is there no notification for a post deleted by a moderator? It seems to me to be an important event.

Comment: Sorry, I usually leave a comment with a deletion which does leave a notification for you, but I figured the situation was fairly clear from the existing comments which is why I didn't. About finding deleted answers: when you go to your profile, then Activity tab, then Answers, there should be a link at the bottom "deleted recent answers". Does that not show the answer for you?

Comment: @MartinEnder It does, and it partially answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: "_Sorry, I usually leave a comment with a deletion which does leave a notification for you_"... well, when you delete the answer it deletes that notification ;).

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware notifications for comments by moderators still show up when the answer is deleted.

Comment: Note that because our site is graduated but does not have its design yet, anyone with 2k+ rep can see your answer. When we get our design, that will change.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah, the new requirement will be 10,000 rep.